# Persistent Time-based Queue

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, redis

I am trying to implement a persistent time-based queue. Elements are added to the queue with a specific time associated with it. The time value represents how long that element will stay at the head of the queue. Multiple clients need to be able to access the element at the head of the queue, how much longer it will be at the head of the queue, and what elements follow the head.

The tools I have at my disposal are a redis server and a mysql server.

Is this type of data structure possible without some sort of helper server managing the queue? How could I implement this in redis or mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with redis's sorted set. You can keep on pushing your data with the time in a sorted set. For example

```
zadd queue 1 value1
zadd queue 2 value2
zadd queue 3 value3
zadd queue 4 value4
zadd queue 5 value5
```

let us say 1 to 5 are your values (time in hours). Now if you query at 3rd hour you will query like this.

```
zrangebyscore queue 3 +inf
```

This will return you

`value3,value4,value5` as result. This will not give you the 1st 2 values as the time is passed. You can design your queue like this.

Also in order to avoid the sorted set being grown too much you can delete the unwanted data periodically using

```
zremrangebyscore queue -inf that_hour-1
```

Learn about sorted set to know more http://redis.io/topics/data-types